# Matching file content with other filenames to extract and merge contents

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two directories.

In directory_1, I have many .txt files

Content of these files (for example file1.txt) are a list of characters

```
file1.txt 
--

rer_098
dfrkk9
```

In directory_2, I have many files, two of them are ‘rer_098’ and ‘dfrkk9’.

Content of these files are as follows:

```
rer_098
--

>123_nbd
sasert
>456_nbd
ffjko
```

```
dfrkk9
--

>789_nbd
figyi
>012_nbd
jjjygk
```

Now in a separate output directory (directory_3), for this above example, I want output files like:

```
file1.txt
--

>123_nbd
sasert
>456_nbd
ffjko
>789_nbd
figyi
>012_nbd
jjjygk
```

and so on for file2.txt

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy to do with just shell. Something like

```sh
for fullname in directory_1/*.txt; do
    file=$(basename "$fullname")
    while read -r line; do
        cat "directory_2/$line"
    done <"$fullname" >"directory_3/$file"
 done
```

Comment: @Bob Works for me with your sample files.

Comment: Make sure you're not doing something like using files with Windows line endings on a non-Windows system.

Comment: Hey Shawn and  Ed Morton,  this script actually works perfectly, seems like some silly file   formatting issues in my machine that gives improper results. I am sorry for my previous comments. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel 'cat {} | parallel -I@@ cat dir_2/@@ > dir_3/{/}' ::: dir_1/*.txt
```

Use two invocations of parallel, the first traverses `dir_1` and pipes its output in a second parallel. This `cat`s the input files and outputs the result `dir_3` keeping the original name from the first parallel invocation.

N.B. The use of the `-I` option to rename the parameter delimiters from the default `{}` to `@@`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in directory_1/*.txt; do
    awk 'NR==FNR{ARGV[ARGC++]="directory_2/"$0; next} 1' "$file" > "directory_3/${file##%/}"
done
```